# Get the number of the active series in an active chart

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a fairly easy macro to activate the next series in an already active chart. (my main macro contains all the formatting stuff).
Problem with this coding, is that i am not able to assign the current active series (already selected in the graph in excel). In a graph with n series (SeriesCollection.Count = n) I want to go from x, to x+1 and if x=n i want to go back to series 1 (so the for/next included here is not necessary if I get the macro to work as intended).

```
Sub NextButton_Click()

Dim cht As Chart
Set cht = ActiveChart

If cht Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Select a chart."
Exit Sub
End If

   With cht

       For SrsIndx = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count
       .SeriesCollection(SrsIndx).Select
       Next SrsIndx

   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: How many `ChartGroup`s do you have?  (e.g. are all of your Series on one Axis, and are they all the same type, bar/Line?)

Comment: Has to work on graphs with two axis as well - but tried both solutions here and they both works fine, many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the General Idea. Step through that code and you can see each series gets selected. You'll need add some object validation as this assumes the selected object is a Series.

Sub CycleSeries()

```
Dim MyObject As ChartObject
Dim MyChart As Chart
Dim SerCol As SeriesCollection
Dim SelSeries As Series
Dim indexSeries As Series
Dim ChartSheet As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer

Set ChartSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set MyObject = ChartSheet.ChartObjects(1)
Set MyChart = MyObject.Chart
Set SerCol = MyChart.SeriesCollection

Set SelSeries = Excel.Application.Selection

For x = 1 To SerCol.Count
    Set indexSeries = SerCol(x)
    If indexSeries.Name = SelSeries.Name Then
        If (x = SerCol.Count) Then
            Set SelSeries = SerCol(1)
            SelSeries.Select
            Exit For
        Else

            Set SelSeries = SerCol(x + 1)
            SelSeries.Select
            Exit For
        End If



    End If

Next x
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

For Simple graphs, just use `PlotOrder`:  If you are not using a Combo Chart (i.e. not mixing Line and Bar charts, and not using the Secondary Axis), then you can just use the following code:

```
IIF(TypeName(Selection)="Series", Selection.PlotOrder, -1)
```

This will return `-1` if you do not have a `Series` selected.

However, this is *actually* the order within the `ChartGroup` - the conditions above were for when there is only 1 `ChartGroup` on the `Chart`.

Otherwise, try using `Name` and a loop:

```
Function ActiveSeriesNumber(ThisSeries AS Series) AS Long
    Dim ThisChart AS Chart, TestNumber AS Long
    ActiveSeriesNumber = -1
    On Error GoTo FunctionError

    Set ThisChart = ThisSeries.Parent.Parent 'Object Model Is Chart.ChartGroup.Series
    For TestNumber = 1 to ThisChart.SeriesCollection.Count
        If ThisChart.SeriesCollection(TestNumber).Name = ThisSeries.Name THen
            ActiveSeriesNumber = TestNumber
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next TestNumber

FunctionError:
    On Error GoTo -1
End Function
```

Use this by calling `ActiveSeriesNumber(Selection)`